# Backbone.js route using regex - Matching a URL that does not end with a given string

Tags: regex, backbone.js, routes, regex-negation

I have to create a route using regex that matches a URL which does not end with a particular word say 'submit'. For example -

> **/login/submit ==> does not match 
>
>   /login/abcsubmit ==> does not match 
>
>   /abc/xyx => Matches**

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

> ((?!(.*?)/\w*submit).*)

like explained in http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route

> this.route(/^((?!(.*?)/\w*submit).*)$/, "functionName");

Answer (score 0):

I had tried @Nestenius regex that he provided and it was still matching the first two example urls that you had provided.  The reason it was is because the regex was not anchored to the start of the string.

You could still use his regex if you add an `^` tag to the beginning of the regex like so:

```
^((?!(.*?)/\w*submit).*)
```

Or you can use this shorter version:

```
^(?!.*submit).*
```

Both will match any string that does not contain "submit" in it.